# Extend MatChip from Angular material. Why input and placeholder are not working anymore?

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am extending the MatChip component from Angular material (everything on version 9).
We want a different appearance and different behaviour than the standard one.

This extended-chip so extends MatChip from Angular material. Then, this extended component is used in different wrappers that add some styles and some specific behaviour.

The wrappers are then placed in the standard **mat-chip-list**.

Everything is rendered properly. Only the placeholder of the input is not working. It is placed at the start of the input, like when the input is empty.

This is the code of the custom chip that extends the base one:

```
export class ChipComponent extends MatChip implements OnChanges {
   my custom code here
}
```

The html is a simple div with custom shape and element projected inside with **ng-content**.

Then there is the specialized wrapper component:

```
<form [form-group]="myFormGroup">
  <custom-chip disableRipple="true">

    <div> some projected content here </div>

  </custom-chip>
</form>
```

And then, this is the code where i use the wrapper in the **mat-chip-list**.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" style="width: 100%">
<mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
  <my-custom-chip-wrapper
    *ngFor="let selected of selectedFruits; let index = index"
    [fruit]="selected"
  >
  </my-custom-chip-wrapper>
  <input
    #fruitInput
    [formControl]="fruitFormControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
    placeholder="My custom chip 1"
    >
</mat-chip-list>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectedFruit($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let f of fruits | async" [value]="f">
    {{f}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

From my investigation, seems that the class **mat-form-field-should-float** is not added to the mat-form-field component and the span that contains the string for the placeholder is not losing the **mat-empty mat-form-field-empty** classes.

This is the result:

[image: Placeholder issue]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? Struggling with the same here...